# What are Mr. Handys capabilities?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The loading screen hints nor the information by buying the item itself are pretty informative. So I just bought one hopfeully expecting some stat window or some stuff like that.

But nothing aswell.
I let him just run around a floor and pick up some stuff which worked fine but didn't feel worth paying money for it, as this is anyway what the whole game is about.

After one or 2 raider attacks in which he got damaged I haven't yet found a way he generates on.

So now I decided to sent him into the wastelands.

And here again I have just open questions.

How is he treat? What are his possibilitys in exploring? how long can i let him outside before he gets in trouble or risking loose him?

And after all: why they put in a tool and say "just pay for it" without releasing what it is able to?

summarized my question is: What are the dos and don'ts for my Mr. Handy?

So I sent him in the wastelands.

Comment: Why it is a duplicate?

Comment: The question has a similar answer to your question, you can check that question out and maybe gt an answer from that.